# searchkick proxy settings ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, proxy, searchkick

I am using the searchkick gem (https://github.com/ankane/searchkick), (It uses elasticsearch) for performing search operations in my rails app.

I am behind a proxy server.

```
rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=ClassName
```

throws a HTTP 403 error, because of the proxy.

Does anyone know how to setup the proxy settings for searchkick

**EDIT:**

I think the problem is that searchkick is using my environment proxy settings to connect to localhost.

Is there a way to specify searchkick to bypass proxy for local addresses without removing all my system proxy settings?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the request is redirected to the proxy which in this case is wrong. You have to add two environment variables to disable proxy for localhost requests:

```
export no_proxy=0.0.0.0,127.0.0.1,localhost
export NO_PROXY=0.0.0.0,127.0.0.1,localhost
```

Searchkick uses *curl* to make request to the elasticsearch API and *curl* reads the proxy exceptions from the no_proxy environment variable.
Next time if you have problems as such please check these steps first:

```
curl localhost # Observe the response if its coming from proxy try the next step
curl --noproxy "*" localhost # Do not send request to the proxy
echo $no_proxy # Check that you have the right environment variable value
```